# how to fix RuntimeError when importing numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

when I'm trying to import numpy on my 64bit computer with python 3.9.0, It is giving me this error:

** On entry to DGEBAL parameter number  3 had an illegal value

** On entry to DGEHRD  parameter number  2 had an illegal value

** On entry to DORGHR DORGQR parameter number  2 had an illegal value

** On entry to DHSEQR parameter number  4 had an illegal value

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 1, in

File "C:\Users\Alizadeh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\numpy_*init*_.py", line 305, in

```
_win_os_check()
```

File "C:\Users\Alizadeh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\numpy_*init*_.py", line 302, in _win_os_check

```
raise RuntimeError(msg.format(__file__)) from None
```

RuntimeError: The current Numpy installation ('C:\Users\Alizadeh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\numpy\**init**.py') fails to pass a sanity check due to a bug in the windows runtime. See this issue for more information: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1207405/fmod-after-an-update-to-windows-2004-is-causing-a.html

#The link above is not the exact link that was shown but it leads to the same page
what is the problem that I am getting this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a windows issue and has to be fixed by Microsoft, however, a fix has not arrived for several weeks now.

Pinning against NumPy 1.19.3 should help (it uses a newer OpenBLAS version, but this caused other problems). This can be achieved using e.g. with `pip install numpy==1.19.3` or similar depending on your setup.

First uninstall your existing numpy setup(if already installed) and try installing to 1.19.3 version

Comment: I currently using numpy 1.19.4, so should I install 1.19.3 version?

Comment: Yes, 1.19.4 has some issues which is not compatible with windows os.
Try uninstalling that and reinstalling 1.19.3